# backup postgres database conf files

Tags: postgresql, backup

I have been exploring ways to backup a Postgres database. It seems the main tool is `pg_dumpall`. However, this doesn't backup the configuration files such as the `hba_file`, `ident_file`, `external_pid_file`, and the `postgresql.conf` file.

If `pg_dumpall` only saves the data in the `data_directory` would it be possible to restore the postgres database without the configuration files? If so, how would I do it? If not, how should I backup the configuration files?

I would like to have a backup such that the cluster can be recreated from scratch.

Comment: `pg_dump` and `pg_dumpall` are meant to create a backup that will be restored to an existing and running Postgres cluster. That means that cluster would already have those files in place. It would be up to you to decide to use the new files or replace them with the files from the cluster you are dumping from.

Comment: There is also the [pg_basebackup](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgbasebackup.html) program. It will take a backup of the files in the cluster $DATADIR. If your setup has the conf files in $DATADIR, say you installed from source, then they would be included. If the conf files are elsewhere say in an `/etc` directory then they would not. Also `pg_basebackup` cannot be to go from one major version of Postgres to another.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver this makes sense and coheres with what I've read in the documentation. If I wish to backup the cluster such that I can recreate everything from scratch, how should I go about this? Would `pg_basebackup` suffice or am I going about this the wrong way? I will add this to the original question.

Comment: Perhaps a more pertinent question is whether backing up only the `data_directory` can be used to spin up a new cluster that has essentially the same data? Are the configuration files necessary to access the data if I were to use the data from `pg_dumpall` to build a new cluster?

Comment: 1) `pg_dumpall` only saves the schema and associated data in the database cluster and does so as text. It does not save the rest of the data in the `data_directory`, for instance `WAL`s. 2) To restore a `pg_dumpall` dump  you have to have a running Postgres instance to restore into. That means there are valid conf files in place. Whether they have the settings you want is another question. 3) You can copy the `data_directory` elsewhere that is what `pg_basebackup` does. You can only start it though with a server of the same major version and I would use same minor version.

Comment: What you want to do depends heavily on how you are installing Postgres, which you have not specified in your question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Postgres was installed on my local using the Ubuntu package manager. I setup another cluster on an external hdd. Other than the major version matching, would moving the data from `pg_dumpall` to a new cluster with default settings created from `pg_createcluster` be sufficient to restore the database? I'm assuming the original conf files are not necessary to setup a new cluster.

Comment: You restore the data from `pg_dumpall` to a new cluster using `psql` and in order to do that the new cluster must be up and running. `pg_dumpall` is a plain text dump so it is not necessary that the major versions match as long as you used the newer version of `pg_dumpall` to dump from an older cluster. The issue with an external hdd is that the data directory maybe there but the conf and log directories will probably not be.

Comment: Yes, that is what I've been struggling with. When I setup the cluster on the external hdd the conf files are still in the system folders of my local machine. In such a situation do I also need to backup the conf files?

Comment: By default on Ubuntu new clusters are set up in `/var/lib/postgresql/`. How did you create the new cluster on the external drive? FYI, using an external drive is not the safest thing to do as there are many ways the data directory can become disassociated from the server.

Comment: @TWhite did you ever find a definitive answer to this? Like you, I want to create a complete backup of the bare minimum information needed to completely replicate my database, and as far as I've been able to determine, we should generally take postgresql.conf, pg_hba.conf, pg_ident.conf, and the external PID file. These files' locations can be found by issuing the commands `SHOW {config_file | hba_file | ident_file | external_pid_file}` in the `psql` commandline. Does that about line up with whatever solution you went with?